# How to calculate limit of summation?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, summation

> How to calculate the following limit?
>
> $$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \left( \dfrac{a^{1/n}}{n+1}+\dfrac{a^{2/n}}{n+1/2}+\dots +\dfrac{a^{n/n}}{n+1/n} \right)$$
> where $a>0$.

Can we convert this summation to the integral?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Squeeze and Riemann sums.

$$\frac{a^{\frac{k}{n}}}{n+\frac{1}{k}}\leq \frac{a^{\frac{k}{n}}}{n}$$

And $$\sum \frac{a^{\frac{k}{n}}}{n}\to\int _0^1 a^x dx=\frac{a-1}{\ln a}.$$

In the other hand 
$$\frac{a^{\frac{k}{n}}}{n+1}\leq \frac{a^{\frac{k}{n}}}{n+\frac{1}{k}}$$

And 
 $$\sum \frac{a^{\frac{k}{n}}}{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1}\sum \frac{a^{\frac{k}{n}}}{n}\to
\frac{a-1}{\ln a}.$$